# Impresion de caracteres especiales en zpl

Tags: zebra, zpl

Hola compañeros tengo una duda con la impresion en zebra, necesito imprimir caracteres especiales (`°` y `ñ`) pero no encuentro aun la manera, en la parte datamatrix me ocurria lo mismo con las barras(`|`) pero lo solucione con la parte de codigo que se muestra ahi intente aplicar la misma pero no me funciono,me pueden ayudar para saber como poder imprimirla?

gracias

```
^XA
^FX -- BORDE DE ETIQUETA
^FO16,16^GB784,1184,1^FS


^FO16,900^GB782,1,1^FS (-- division vertical)


^FX -- DATAMATRIX
^FO570,940
^BQN,2,6
^FDMM,B0100P|219200001||10|20092021^FS


^FX -- PROVEEDOR
^FO615,420^A0R,40,30^FB300,4^^FDDATOS DEL PROVEEÑOR^FS
^FO559,420^A0R,45,32^FB300,3^^FDINICIATIVA EMPRESARIAL^FS
^FO525,560^A0R,40,30^FB300,4^^FD^FS

^FO430,400^GB370,1,1^FS (-- sep vertical)
^FO560,20^GB0,880,2,B^FS (-- sep horizontal)
^FO560,320^GB0,880,2,B^FS (-- sep horizontal)


^FX -- CANTIDAD TOTAL
^FO525,25^A0R,25,40^FDCANTIDAD TOTAL ^FS
^FO460,110^A0R,40,90,3^FD3000^FS

^FX -- ORDEN DE COMPRA
^FO525,410^A0R,25,40^FDPO.NO^FS
^FO460,510^A0R,40,90,3^FD23^FS

^FO432,16^GB0,885,2,B^FS (-- sep horiz)

^FX -- LOTE MASTER
^FO400,24^A0R,25,45^FDLOTE MASTER^FS
^FO330,150^A0R,40,90^FD^FS

^FO305,16^GB0,1184,2,B^FS (-- sep horiz)

^FX -- NUMERO DE PARTE
^FO270,24^A0R,25,45^FDNO. PARTE^FS
^FO210,150^A0R,40,90^FDCAJ-0029^FS

^FO190,16^GB0,1184,2,B^FS (-- sep horiz)

^FX -- DESCRIPCIÓN
^FO160,24^A0R,25,45^FDDESCRIPCION^FS
^FO105,24^A0R,40,45^FDCAJA AGAVE EL COMPADRE 750 ML 12 PZ^FS

^FO95,16^GB0,885,2,B^FS (-- sep horiz)

^LRY^FO15,15
^GB15,885,80^FS
^FX -- TIPO DE ETIQUETA 
^FO25,565^A0R,50,90^FDMASTER^FA200^FS

^FX -- EMPRESA - ALMACEN
^FO55,28^A0R,25,45^FD^FA200^FS
^FO20,28^A0R,25,45^FN2^FA200^FS

^FX -- DETALLE DE CAJAS
^FO515,920^A0R,23,20^FDDETALLES POR CONTENEDORES ^FS
^FO465,920^A0R,25,27^FDNO. DE CONTENEDORES ^FS
^FO415,1000^A0R,40,80^FD30^FS
^FO360,915^A0R,23,23^FDCANTIDAD POR CONTENEDOR^FS
^FO315,1000^A0R,40,80^FD30^FS


^FX -- FECHA DE RECIBIMIENTO
^FO265,920^A0R,30,25^FDFECHA  DE RECIBIMIENTO:^FS
^FO200,930^A0R,40,40^FD03/08/21 14:36^FS


^FX -- LOTE PROVEEDOR
^FO145,940^A0R,25,30^FDLOTE PROVEEDOR:^FS
^FO60,940^A0R,45,50^FD 21645435^FS

^FO60,900^GB0,300,2,B^FS (-- sep horiz)

^FX -- EMPRESA - 
^FO20,905^A0R,25,30^FDPOWERED BY ^FA200^FS

^FN2^FD$ALMACEN^FS (ALMACEN)

^XZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolvi por si a alguien le sirve solo basta agregar ^CI128 y ^asn de la siguiente manera

```
 "^FX" + //-- EMPRESA - ALMACEN
 "^CI28" +
 "^FO55,28^ASN^A0R,25,45^FDCompañeros || de 4°^FA200^FS" +
 "^FO20,28^A0R,25,45^FN2^FA200^FS"
```